# httprequestmessage.createresponse() doesnt exist in System.net.http

Tags: c#, .net, http, asp.net-core, graph

I am trying to using the updated version of GraphController file(https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/examples/blob/master/src/AspNetWebApi/WebApi/Controllers/GraphQLController.cs). The file is using httprequest.createresponse() method inside the class. However, I am not able to use it. Did the method become obsolete. Is there any way that I can use the createresponse() method?

Answer (score 0):

[Request.CreateResponse in asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757245/request-createresponse-in-asp-net-core)