# asp.net core mvc 1.1 return statuscode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

asp.net core 1.1 return statuscode(198), returns nothing.
I call this action by Postman and it triggers the action and code runs but on postman after a few seconds says could not get any response. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right, I want to return a network response with specific code.

```
    [Route("api/Add/{Id}/{title}/{desc}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Add(string Id, string title, string desc, IFormFile image)
    {

        return StatusCode(198);

    }
```

Comment: First of all, there is no HTTP status code of 198 so that is really going to confuse things. What are you really trying to do here?

Comment: Yes there is not but I want to respond this and in my android app check if the status code is 198 do something. for some reason I can't get response content there.

Comment: Status codes mean specific things, don't try to abuse them. Get your app to return a proper code with come content that means something to the app.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [ASP.NET Core - How to return a specific status code and no contents from Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/asp-net-core-how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-control).

You are returning a status code properly (even if it's not a valid status code). So perhaps you have middleware or an action filter that is causing the issue.