# Return NotFound() or unhandled exception with a 404 page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently using ASP.NET Core, how do I set a 404 default page for unhandled exceptions or `NotFound()`?

```
IActionResult Foo()
{
    throw new Exception("Message!");
}

IActionResult Bar()
{
    return NotFound("Message!");
}
```

I think there is a `IApplicationBuilder.UseExceptionHandler` method to set an error page, but I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/asp-net-core-how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-control

Comment: @CarlosFerreira That is a different question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) under **Configuring status code pages**

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/error/{0}");
```

You'll need an `ErrorController` which could look like:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller 
{
    public IActionResult Index(string errorCode)
    {
        return View(errorCode);
    }
}
```

Your views (in the Error folder) would need to be called:

- 500.cshtml
- 404.cshtml

...etc

Comment: After I make these pages, if I `return NotFound("MyError!")` how do I catch the error string?

Comment: Using this method, you can't... It just redirects based on status code