# How can I return custom error message for error status code 401 in .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

Please help me to display a custom error message for an error status code 401 in .Net Core WebApi.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a specific status code and no contents from Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-controller)

Comment: Do you need it for the entire API or for the specific Action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP Core documentation explains how to handle custom error responses:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usestatuscodepages

In your case, you could try `app.UseStatusCodePages` in your startup `Configure` method(add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`)

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Custom Unauthorized request");
    }
});
//other middlewars
```

Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
{
   return Unauthorized();
}
```