# Azure does not display custom error message for hosted .net core API

Tags: c#, azure, api, asp.net-core

I have the following API endpoint:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] LoginViewModel credentials)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = await _facade.SomeMethodThatFailsAndThrowsCustomCode4001(credentials);
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (CustomException cEx)
        {
            return StatusCode(4001, new { Message = cEx.FriendlyMessage ?? "" }); //Message = Our custom user friendly message
        }
    }
```

When hosted on external server through IIS, these messages were returned perfectly.  When hosted on Azure, the messages are not showing, and this is the response received:

```
{
  "Message": ""
}
```

I have read about [Policies allowed in on-error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-error-handling-policies), but this means I will need to register my `.Net Core` API with the API management in Azure, and not sure if this is necessary.

What would be required to be configured to allow our custom messages returned through our API hosted in Azure?

Comment: Is the status code 4001 as you return it? What happens if you hard code the message for example new { Message = "My test Message" }?

Comment: When you say, "hosted on Azure", can you clarify if you mean an Azure App Service?

Comment: @tnk479 That is correct

Comment: And you want to use 4001 as a valid status code?

Comment: @tnk479 Yes that is what I want to do

Comment: @monstertjie_za You will alway get HttpStatus code 200, because you api `{yourController}/login` is a http request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [read RFC doc about `HTTP Status Codes`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml).

> 1xx: Informational - Request received, continuing process

> 2xx: Success - The action was successfully received, understood, and accepted

> 3xx: Redirection - Further action must be taken in order to complete the request

> 4xx: Client Error - The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled

> 5xx: Server Error - The server failed to fulfill an apparently valid request

**First, after testing, the upper limit of the usable range of StatusCode is 999. When `StatusCode >999`, errors will be reported all the time.**

[image]

**Second, you also can handle custom status code in `Startup.cs`.**

```
if (env.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Custom Unauthorized request");
    }
});
//other middlewars
```

## Related Post:

[1. How can I return custom error message for error status code 401 in .Net Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220711/how-can-i-return-custom-error-message-for-error-status-code-401-in-net-core)

[2. How to return a specific status code and no contents from Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-controller)