# C# Async Method: How to return an HttpStatusCode?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PostQueuePrimaryInsured([FromRoute]string policyNumber, [FromBody]Queue<FormRequest> body) {
    HttpStatusCode result = _service.DoSomething(result);

    return result;
}
```

How do I make it return the HttpStatusCode result? I can't figure out the correct syntax. I can have it return Ok(), NotFound(), etc. but I don't want a large if-else block checking for each status code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a specific status code and no contents from Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690114/how-to-return-a-specific-status-code-and-no-contents-from-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I found. Please let me know if there is a better solution.

```
return StatusCode((int)result);
```