# new ObjectResult(null) StatusCode set to 200 returns 204

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, azure-functions

I have azure function returning `Task<IActionResult>`, when I create new `ObjectResult` object (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace), set its body to null and set `StatusCode` to 200 it actually returns 204 (no content).

```
ObjectResult objectResult = new ObjectResult(null);
objectResult.StatusCode = 200;
return objectResult;
```

But when I set `objectResult.StatusCode` to 201 (created) it returns created. I had to put dummy value to `ObjectResult` constructor parameter to finally get 200:

```
ObjectResult objectResult = new ObjectResult("autotest");
```

Is this behavior expected or is it bug?

Comment: There *is* no content. 204 is the correct status code. Use `StatusCodeResult` if you want to return an explicit status only

Comment: I would agree but when I have set 201 it returned 201 when there was also no content, so what is the difference between 200 and 201 in this context? Looks inconsistent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you just return a StatusCodeResult?!

```
return new StatusCodeResult(200);
```

Comment: That is the solution to avoid using ObjectResult, I was trying to use answer from this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/37690852/8611327 but without success. Thanks.